# php2connect, encrypt and workaround

Tags: php

I have used this script, but it is not serving me well anymore. I have to visit mysite.com/serv.php to call the script. So, first here is the script:

```
$ip = "ip";
$user = "user";
$pass = "password";

if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");

if(!($con = ssh2_connect($ip, 22))){
    echo "<font color='red'>fail: unable to establish connection</font>\n";
} else {   

    if(!ssh2_auth_password($con, $user, $pass)) {
        echo "fail: unable to authenticate";
    } else {
        echo "Sucessful";
        if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, "/home/boza/serv.sh" ))) {
            echo "fail: unable to execute command";
        } else {
            stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
            $data = "";
            while ($buf = fread($stream,4096)) {
                $data .= $buf;
            }
            fclose($stream);
        }
    }
}
```

The script works well, but I want to have some changes in it.
1. I would like to add md5 hash into it, to make it more secure
2. I would like for the script to not be executed when visiting serv.php, but by pressing a button to make an ajax call.
3. I would like there to be user feedback, like "sucessful" or "fail"... like I did now, with live ajax or something without refreshing site.

I have googled and I have tried to put md5('xxxx') into the script, I have got a weird errors and I'm sure I was doing something wrong.

Could someone help me with this case please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a form to launch script only when pressing a button like :

```
$ip = "ip";
$user = "user";
$pass = "password";

if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");
echo '<form action="#" method="POST">';
echo '<input type="submit" name="launch" value="1" />'
echo '</form>';

if($_POST['launch']==1){
    if(!($con = ssh2_connect($ip, 22))){
        echo "<font color='red'>fail: unable to establish connection</font>\n";
    } else {   

        if(!ssh2_auth_password($con, $user, $pass)) {
            echo "fail: unable to authenticate";
        } else {
            echo "Sucessful";
            if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, "/home/boza/serv.sh" ))) {
                echo "fail: unable to execute command";
            } else {
                stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
                $data = "";
                while ($buf = fread($stream,4096)) {
                    $data .= $buf;
                }
                fclose($stream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and for password you can use "baba" class or if it is only a problem of source reading you can use a simple reversable encrypt function like a XOR encryption, BEWARE it is only to make the password not directly redable from source but it is not a perfect securisation

example :

```
 function XORin($key='asimpletext', $text='pwd'){
     for($i=0;$i<strlen($text);$i++)
     {
         for($j=0;$j<strlen($key);$j++,$i++)
         {
             $outText .= $text{$i} ^ $key{$j};
         }
     }
     return $outText;
 }

 function XORout($key='asimpletext', $text='pwd'){(){
     for($i=0;$i<strlen($text);$i++)
     {
         for($j=0;$j<strlen($key);$j++,$i++)
         {
             $outText .= $key{$j} ^ $text{$i};
         }
     }
     return $outText;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for button solution xavier Z. It works but there is an error when i enter a page. Notice: Undefined index: launch in /var/www/serv.php on line 11

Comment: what about some non refresh response?

Answer (score 0):

`MD5` is a one way hash and it would not be able to secure your connection. It is also weak and not as strong as before. I would not recommend it for any level of security

What you should look at is  `authenticating with public key authentication` look at this

[Example Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-connect.php#104758)

```
class NiceSSH { 
    // SSH Host 
    private $ssh_host = 'myserver.example.com'; 
    // SSH Port 
    private $ssh_port = 22; 
    // SSH Server Fingerprint 
    private $ssh_server_fp = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; 
    // SSH Username 
    private $ssh_auth_user = 'username'; 
    // SSH Public Key File 
    private $ssh_auth_pub = '/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub'; 
    // SSH Private Key File 
    private $ssh_auth_priv = '/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa'; 
    // SSH Private Key Passphrase (null == no passphrase) 
    private $ssh_auth_pass; 
    // SSH Connection 
    private $connection; 

    public function connect() { 
        if (!($this->connection = ssh2_connect($this->ssh_host, $this->ssh_port))) { 
            throw new Exception('Cannot connect to server'); 
        } 
        $fingerprint = ssh2_fingerprint($this->connection, SSH2_FINGERPRINT_MD5 | SSH2_FINGERPRINT_HEX); 
        if (strcmp($this->ssh_server_fp, $fingerprint) !== 0) { 
            throw new Exception('Unable to verify server identity!'); 
        } 
        if (!ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($this->connection, $this->ssh_auth_user, $this->ssh_auth_pub, $this->ssh_auth_priv, $this->ssh_auth_pass)) { 
            throw new Exception('Autentication rejected by server'); 
        } 
    } 
    public function exec($cmd) { 
        if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($this->connection, $cmd))) { 
            throw new Exception('SSH command failed'); 
        } 
        stream_set_blocking($stream, true); 
        $data = ""; 
        while ($buf = fread($stream, 4096)) { 
            $data .= $buf; 
        } 
        fclose($stream); 
        return $data; 
    } 
    public function disconnect() { 
        $this->exec('echo "EXITING" && exit;'); 
        $this->connection = null; 
    } 
    public function __destruct() { 
        $this->disconnect(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: thing is there are other ftp users and I would like to hide it from them. But not with public keys :/

Comment: NO server is secured if other people have access .... except you encrypt your entire php code ... even advance developers can crack that

Comment: It is not about that, that i would use ioncube to hide all the code or so. I just want to hide password. But not with base64